# How to set dropdown list items with .addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you set the dropdown box options using .addClass in javascript/jquery?

I need to set the options in the dropdown box to Link 1,Link 2, Link 3 etc but I cant figure out how to do it using .addClass

```
$hyperlinkElement = $('<a>Manage</a>').attr('href', '/Client/Visit/' + records[index].clientId).addClass('btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle');
```

Comment: `addClass` adds class strings to the elements class list. That's all it does. What "options" are you trying to set exactly? Link 1, Link 2, etc mean nothing out of context.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
$('dropdown-menu').addClass('item');
```

you only add a class - not an item.

For adding an item - you should use:

```
$('dropdown-menu').append("<a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Link 1</a>");
```

You also have to set an event handler to trigger this:

```
<a class"manage">Manage</a>

<script>
   $(".manage").on( "click", function() {
      $('dropdown-menu').append("<a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Link 1</a>");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. however, what im asking is if there is a way to set the options of the dropdown list by using .addClass? I have rephrased my question as it may have been unclear.